# Issues after Marlin file browser installation?

Tags: python, update-manager, repository

Someday ago I tried the Marlin file browser (a nice crossover between thunar, nautilus and windows explorer) from elementary-dev PPA. Then I've encountered some troubles in updating packages. Playonlinux (that I sometimes use) stopped to work but other python apps seems to work (however I've problems at every system update).

edit: It seems the PPAs I've disabled in Synaptic are still present in ubuntu configuration. Restoring "official sources.list" can  resolve my issues? Thanks in advance for your help :)

```
raffaele@Natty:~$ LANG=en_US;sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for raffaele: 
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty InRelease
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-security InRelease             
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security InRelease                        
Ign http://archive.canonical.com natty InRelease                               
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates InRelease               
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed InRelease              
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports InRelease             
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty Release.gpg                               
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty InRelease                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security Release.gpg                      
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-security Release.gpg            
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates Release.gpg                       
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed Release.gpg                      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com natty Release.gpg                             
Get:1 http://extras.ubuntu.com natty Release.gpg [72 B]                        
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports Release.gpg                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security Release                          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com natty Release                                 
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty Release                          
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-security Release                 
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates Release                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty Release                            
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed Release                 
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports Release                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe amd64 Packages          
Hit http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner Sources                         
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/restricted Sources                        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main amd64 Packages              
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages        
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted amd64 Packages        
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main TranslationIndex            
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse TranslationIndex      
Hit http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner amd64 Packages                  
Ign http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner TranslationIndex                
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/main Sources                              
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/universe Sources                          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Sources                                
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/multiverse Sources                        
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/universe amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/restricted amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/multiverse amd64 Packages                 
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/main TranslationIndex                     
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/multiverse TranslationIndex               
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/restricted TranslationIndex               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main amd64 Packages               
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main TranslationIndex                       
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/universe TranslationIndex                 
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-security/universe Sources       
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-security/main Sources                     
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-security/multiverse Sources               
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-security/restricted Sources               
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/universe Sources                  
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/main Sources                      
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/multiverse Sources                
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/restricted Sources                
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/universe amd64 Packages           
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages         
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages         
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/main TranslationIndex             
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex       
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/restricted TranslationIndex       
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/universe TranslationIndex         
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/universe Sources       
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/main Sources           
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/multiverse Sources     
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/restricted Sources               
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/universe amd64 Packages          
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/main amd64 Packages              
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/multiverse amd64 Packages        
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/restricted amd64 Packages        
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/main TranslationIndex            
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/multiverse TranslationIndex      
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/universe TranslationIndex        
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/universe Sources                
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/main Sources                    
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/restricted Sources              
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/universe amd64 Packages         
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/main TranslationIndex           
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex     
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/restricted TranslationIndex     
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/universe TranslationIndex       
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/main Translation-it                       
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/multiverse Translation-it                 
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/restricted Translation-it                 
Hit http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/universe Translation-it                   
Ign http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner Translation-en                  
Ign http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner Translation-it                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en               
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main Translation-en    
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main Translation-it
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-it
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse Translation-it      
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted Translation-en      
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted Translation-it      
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Translation-en        
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Translation-it
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/main Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/main Translation-it
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/multiverse Translation-it
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/restricted Translation-it
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-updates/universe Translation-it
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/main Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/main Translation-it
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/multiverse Translation-it
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/restricted Translation-it
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-proposed/universe Translation-it
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/main Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/main Translation-it
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/multiverse Translation-it
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/restricted Translation-it
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.fastbull.org natty-backports/universe Translation-it
Fetched 72 B in 2s (27 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

raffaele@Natty:~$ LAN=en_US;sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "it_IT:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_US"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx (7.10.2-0ubuntu2.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules is already managed by x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf.
dpkg: error processing libgl1-mesa-glx (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglu1-mesa:
 libglu1-mesa depends on libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not configured yet.
  Package libgl1 is not installed.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx which provides libgl1 is not configured yet.
  Package libgl1-mesa-swx11 which provides libgl1 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libglu1-mesa (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwxgtk2.8-0:
 libwxgtk2.8-0 depends on libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not configured yet.
  Package libgl1 is not installed.
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx which provides libgl1 is not configured yet.
  Package libgl1-mesa-swx11 which provides libgl1 is not installed.
 libwxgtk2.8-0 depends on libglu1-mesa | libglu1; however:
  Package libglu1-mesa isNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                   No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                             No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                          not configured yet.
  Package libglu1 is not installed.
  Package libglu1-mesa which provides libglu1 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libwxgtk2.8-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-wxgtk2.8:
 python-wxgtk2.8 depends on libwxgtk2.8-0 (>= 2.8.11.0); however:
  Package libwxgtk2.8-0 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-wxgtk2.8 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of playonlinux:
 playonlinux depends on python-wxgtk2.8; however:
  Package python-wxgtk2.8 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing playonlinux (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgl1-mesa-glx
 libglu1-mesa
 libwxgtk2.8-0
 python-wxgtk2.8
 playonlinux
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

raffaele@Natty:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 11.04 _Natty Narwhal_ - Release amd64 (20110427.1)]/ natty main restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu.fastbull.org/ubuntu/ natty restricted main #Added by software-properties
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 11.04 _Natty Narwhal_ - Release amd64 (20110427.1)]/ natty main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.


## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.



# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
deb http://ubuntu.fastbull.org/ubuntu/ natty main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://ubuntu.fastbull.org/ubuntu/ natty universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu.fastbull.org/ubuntu/ natty-security universe main multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties
deb http://ubuntu.fastbull.org/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu.fastbull.org/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe main multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties
deb http://ubuntu.fastbull.org/ubuntu/ natty-proposed universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu.fastbull.org/ubuntu/ natty-proposed universe main multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties
deb http://ubuntu.fastbull.org/ubuntu/ natty-backports universe main multiverse restricted
deb-src http://ubuntu.fastbull.org/ubuntu/ natty-backports universe main multiverse restricted #Added by software-properties
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tobydox/ultrastardx/ubuntu maverick main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tobydox/ultrastardx/ubuntu maverick main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu natty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/banshee-team/ppa/ubuntu natty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu natty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu natty main
# deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian natty contrib
# deb-src http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian natty contrib

# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernel-ppa/ppa/ubuntu natty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kernel-ppa/ppa/ubuntu natty main
# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu natty-getdeb apps
# deb-src http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu natty-getdeb apps
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cdemu/ppa/ubuntu natty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/cdemu/ppa/ubuntu natty main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementaryart/elementary-dev/ubuntu natty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementaryart/elementary-dev/ubuntu natty main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I suggest use `ppa-purge` to reinstate the standard ubuntu installation that had been upgraded by the PPA

i.e.

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementaryart/elementary-dev`

Edit:

from your revised trace there is this error: `update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules is already managed by x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf.`

This is described in this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/833841) - the suggested solution was to remove your nvidia driver from the Addition Drivers windows (deactivate it), make sure `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` works before reactivating the nvidia driver again.

Comment: I've tried a few other python apps and now seems to work well... Seems to be a mesa problem (which should be different from nvidia opengl, I suppose). Playonlinux doesn't work anymore. Luckily the apps works with plain wine menu :D

Comment: I've disabled all PPAs but the wxgtk2.8 problem remains. If I would restore original settings of updating system?

Comment: please can you edit your question with the output of `LANG=en_US;sudo apt-get update` and `LAN=en_US;sudo apt-get upgrade` - please also include `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` - thanks.

Comment: @Hadden - have updated with latest info.

Comment: Now seems to work perfectly. I've disabled also the Nvidia PPA (most updated but less tested for ubuntu). Thank you for your help :)